# Microsoft LUIS: Prebuilt entities and Intent

Tags: azure-language-understanding

If I have a prebuilt entity temperature.

And how can I match it to my intent AskTemperature

Because In the AskTemperature.

It can't add the prebuilt entity.

So how do I implement to make entity temperature belongs to the intent AskTemperature?

Thank you!!!

Comment: What should your intent detect exactly? Can you add some examples of sentences that you would like to detect?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide an example of the labeled utterances, the community may be better equipped to answer your question. That said... Once you train your model, the model should automatically assign the prebuilt entity to the recognized tokens (words, numbers, etc).

After training your model, if this recognition doesn't occur, you may need to train with more straight forward utterances (e.g. "Is the temperature in Redmond right now 16 celsius?").

If all of this doesn't work, then posting relevant portions of your LUIS model may aid in getting help from the SO community.

Answer (score 0):

After you trained your model/intents, the prebuilt entities should be assigned to that utterances.

I have this utterance: are there room available on 12/21/2016?

When I tried to assign the 12/21/2016 to "datetimeV2" entity directly, I cannot find that prebuilt entity; but after I trained it, it shows automatically.

[Click to see this image (cannot post image since reputation not reaching 10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncIRA.png)

Hope this helps!